# Drop-down for country-states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, drop-down-menu

Hi I want to implement a drop-down for countries and states.The states drop-down should change its values according to the country selected.
Is there any plugin or gem to do this in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Carmen plugin:

http://autonomousmachine.com/posts/2009/4/1/carmen-a-rails-plugin-for-geographic-names-and-abbreviations

You can also check this other stackoverflow post:

[Ruby on Rails Country/State Select Enigma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976173/ruby-on-rails-country-state-select-enigma)

Comment: Did this help you along your way?

Answer (score 2):

Country State Select is a library that provides an easy API to generate Country and State / Province dropdowns for use in forms.

When implemented correctly, a State / Province dropdown is filled with appropriate regions based on what Country a user has selected.

After it's version `2.0.0` it also dependent to `simple_form 3.2`

you can also find cities according to the state and country name by using this gem

**https://rubygems.org/gems/country_state_select**

Comment: Please note the dependency on `simple_form ~> 3.2`, your form must be using `simple_form` for this to work.

Comment: after 2.0.0 it require simple_form

Comment: Thanks for updating that Arv