# Rails: Undefined local variable or method with Country-State-Select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working on a Rails application where I need to list countries and their corresponding states/provinces. For this function, I am using the [Country-State-Select](https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select) gem.

I have included the gem in my Gemfile

```
gem 'country_state_select'
```

And installed it

```
bundle install
```

However, the official documentation used simple_form objects while I am using the default rails form objects.

Here's my form field for **country**, which works very fine:

```
<%= form.label :country %>
<%= form.select :country_field, collection: CountryStateSelect.countries_collection %>
```

However, the form field for **state** which is below:

```
<%= form.label :state %>
<%= form.select :state_field, CountryStateSelect.state_options(form: form, field_names: { country: country_field, state: state_field } ) %>
```

keeps throwing errors:

> undefined local variable or method `country_field'

Here's the simple form implementation of it in the [Country-State-Select](https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select) gem documentation, which I am trying to convert to the default rails form objects:

```
<%= options = { form: f, field_names: { :country => :country_field, :state => :state_field } } 
f.input :state_field, CountryStateSelect.state_options(options) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learnt from **Arvind Vyas** the owner of the [Country-Select-Select](https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select) gem in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066744/11793091) that the gem depends on the [simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) gem.

So the best bet is to integrate the [simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) gem into the application or look for other alternatives, since the default rails form which I am using will not work for the implementation.